How can I express these two sets and find their intersection by Mathematica?

My code:
M = Interval[{-1, 2}]
N = Reduce[ForAll[{y, x}, x \[Element] M, y == 0.5*x^2 - 1], Reals]
Intersection[M, N]

Gives an error message :

Set::wrsym: Symbol N is Protected.


Intersection::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 2 in Interval[{-1,2}][Intersection]N.

The answer is obviously (-1,1).
I want to know how to correct code.

It is good practice using Mathematica that all user-defined symbols/variable/functions should start with a lower-case letter, because all built-in functions in Mathematica start with capital letters. N is one of them.


Should not use N since N is a function.
Use Exists instead of ForAll.
Intersection only work for finte sets.

Clear["Global`*"];
m = Interval[{-1, 2}];
n = ImplicitRegion[
   Reduce[Exists[x, x ∈ m, y == 1/2*x^2 - 1], Reals], {y}];
Reduce[x ∈ m && x ∈ n, x]



We can also directly use FunctionRange to find the set of n.

m = Interval[{-1, 2}]; 
n = 
 ImplicitRegion[FunctionRange[1/2*x^2 - 1, x, y], y]
Reduce[x ∈ m && x ∈ n, x]


thanks
I modified some codes because the question requires a open interval.
m = ImplicitRegion[Reduce[x > -1 && x < 2, Reals], {x}] n = ImplicitRegion[    Reduce[Exists[x, x \[Element] m, y == 1/2*x^2 - 1], Reals], {y}]; Reduce[x \[Element] m && x \[Element] n, x]
What are the best practices for working with open intervals in Mathematica?
I didn't find a built-in function that handles open interval.

@neo742   Using m = ImplicitRegion[-1 < x < 2, {x}]  to express the open interval is sufficience.

You can use IntervalIntersection :
f[x_] := x^2/2 - 1
Reduce[x ∈ 
  IntervalIntersection[Interval[{-1, 2}], f@Interval[{-1, 2}]], x]

yields $-1\leq x_1\leq1$
Please note: the issue of closed, open, half closed intervals is not addressed.

(+1)  We can use https://steampiano.net/msc/ to translate the special characters in Mathematica.

@cvgmt thanks for that information (and vote)
